# How to communicate between a dialog and parent Controller in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a MainController and when I press a certain button, a custom dialog (loaded from a custom FXML file) pops up from that MainController class.
Now, in that dialog, there are some text input fields and a button. When I press that button, the dialog should close and the data from the input fields should be sent to the parent controller (which is the MainController in this case).
So far I have thought of an approach:

1. First, by using a singleton class to store the values
2. Second, by sending the *dialog* instance through the loader method during the creation of the dialog

```
DialogController dialogController = loader.getController();
dialogController.setContent(dialog);
```

But this way, I fear there will be memory leaks and such. Is there any better way to do this, such as using interfaces? Some help will be really appreciated!

My code so far:

*MainController.java*

```
 private void openDialog() {
        try {
            JFXDialogLayout content = new JFXDialogLayout();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("dialogs/dialog.fxml"));
            loader.load();
            JFXDialog dialog = new JFXDialog(stackPaneRoot, loader.getRoot(), JFXDialog.DialogTransition.CENTER);
            DialogController dialogController = loader.getController();
            dialogController.setContent(dialog);
            dialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

*DialogController.java*

```
public class DialogController {

    @FXML
    private TextField nameInput;
    private JFXDialog dialog;

    @FXML
    void onCloseClick(ActionEvent event) {
        dialog.close();
        // Util is the singleton class to store the data
        Util.getInstance().setName(nameInput.getText());
    }

    public void setContent(JFXDialog dialog) {
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you've setup the dialog/fxml correctly then the dialog controller should already have access to the fields and you wouldn't need to "setContent" You might need to do something with the main controller though.

Comment: Hey, @matt Thanks for your suggestion. However, I think you didn't get what I'm trying to do. I want to pass the data from the dialog to the parent controller. If you're familiar with android, then it'd be the concept applied to the communication between a fragment and the parent activity using interface.

Comment: You're right, I don't get what you're trying to do. Why are you passing the 'dialog' as the argument, and not the parent controller? If you want to pass the main controller, then have 'setContent' set the main controller.

Comment: Oh, maybe I see a bit better. You've got a dialog/stage that you want to close. You've also got the main controller that you want to interact with. You don't "need" to set the content there. You can get the stage through the jfx hierarchy.

Comment: Instead of dialog.close() you can use `nameInput.getScene().getWindow()` that will get you the dialog.

Comment: Got it now! I can use ```nameInput.getScene().getWindow()``` to close the dialog and pass the parent controller instance through the method setContent() to get the input data. Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

In my app, I ended up with the below. Basically, I call my addUser method on my main view when a user clicks "Add User" button. I set the pane of my plain Dialog object to my NewUserDialog.fxml (I am using scene builder btw). You'll see in my example below. It's the most eloquent way of doing it that I've found without having to resort to static classes.

Note that, my NewUserDialog.fxml cannot contain a reference to a controller, because in the FXMLLoader object, we use setController method to pass in the controller we instantiate. We wait for the user to select Apply, and then call the public controllers getData() method, which just returns a string of the firstNameField.

This way, you can inject objects into the controller class with a constructor or method, or just create a public function in the controller that returns an object model of your data and go from there.

```
private void addUser(ActionEvent event) {
        newDialog = new Dialog();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(app.getClass().getResource("fxml/NewUserDialog.fxml"));
        newUserController = new NewUserDialogController();
        loader.setController(newUserController);
        try {
            newDialog.setDialogPane(loader.load());   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Error("Add user dialog class could not load: \n" + e);
        }
        
        Optional<ButtonType> result = newDialog.showAndWait();
        if (result.get() == ButtonType.APPLY){
            System.out.println(newUserController.getData());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cancel");
        }
}
```

And this is my dialog controller

```
public class NewUserDialogController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TextField firstNameField;
@FXML
private TextField lastNameField;
@FXML
private TextField middleNameField;
@FXML
private TextField profileNameField;
@FXML
private ComboBox<?> roleComboBox;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    
}    

public String getData() {
    return firstNameField.getText();
}
}
```